# Get date from datepicker using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp-classic, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying get two dates from datepickers that I have made using the following html/classic asp code:

```
<%
    Response.Write("The start date is <br><input type='text' class = 'datepicker' id='date1' value='7/01/2015' />")
    Response.Write("The end date is <br><input type='text' class = 'datepicker' id='date2' value='"&date()&"' />")
%>
```

Here is the jQuery for making the datePickers

```
function datePicker(t) {
    $(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker();
        $(".datepicker").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "mm-dd-yy");
    })
}
```

When I try and print the dates to the screen with the following code, it returns `[object Object]` rather than a string like the other sample code for this problem indicates it should. I have also tried to use the JSON.stringify() method to turn this into a string, but got no working results.

```
function test() {
    var dataAsObject = $(".datepicker[name=date1]").datepicker('getDate');
    window.alert(dataAsObject);
}
```

The other variations of accomplishing this that I have found (using val() instead of datepicker.('getDate'), using $("#datepicker").on("change"...)) give similar results. How can I resolve this issue? I should say that I would prefer solutions that don't use .on("change"...), as I would like to use these two dates for an ajax call and want to be able to send the default dates, so the screen isn't blank until the user selects their dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not assigning any names to the datepickers, only ids. So use the id to get the dates:

```
var dataAsObject = $("#date2").datepicker('getDate');
window.alert(dataAsObject);
```